# UNIX_TIMESTAMP returns 0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return the value by using unix_timestamp function but it behaves strange.

```
set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 1000) /* 1339947588 */
set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 2000) /* 1339948188 */
set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 3000) /* 1339948788 */

set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 4000) /* 0 */
set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 5000) /* 0 */
set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 6000) /* 0 */
set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 7000) /* 0 */

set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 8000) /* 1339949388 */
set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 9000) /* 1339949988 */
set @currentdate:= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() + 10000) /* 1339950588 */
```

Why it returns the value of 0 for the values between 4000-7000 ?

What I see that the answer related by the current time because the interval, that gives the 0, changes by the time passing. What can be the reason ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not strange at all. You are adding some numbers to the result of `NOW()` before calling `UNIX_TIMSETAMP()` on the result. I think you want to call `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` *before*  adding your values:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) + 4000
```

or just

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 4000
```

Both of these will add 4000 *seconds* to the current time. Another solution is to use the [INTERVAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) keyword to add time units to a date:

```
NOW() + INTERVAL 4000 SECOND
```

According to [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), when `NOW() + 4000` is evaluated, `NOW()` returns a number in this format: `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu`, e.g., `20071215235026.000000`. If you add 4000 to this you may or may not get something which resembles a real date. As you can see, you will *not*  add seconds or any other defined entity. If you get a correct date `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` will return a timestamp, otherwise it will return `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `NOW()` for testing in that way can lead to confusing results. So let's put it into a variable:

```
SET @now=NOW();
```

Let's have a look at it:

```
SELECT @now;
-> 2012-06-17 17:42:01
```

Hm. Maybe we want to use it in a numerical context?

```
SET @now=NOW()+0;
SELECT @now;
-> 20120617174201
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@now);
-> 1339947721
```

Aah. What is that? It is the current date and time. `2012-06-17 17:42:01`, and its UNIX timestamp.

And now?

```
SELECT @now + 2000;
-> 20120617176201
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@now + 2000);
-> 0
```

According to the logic above, it would represent `2012-06-17 17:62:01`. This is invalid, which makes `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` whine.

If we do, however,

```
SELECT @now + 7000;
-> 20120617181201
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@now + 7000);
-> 1339949521
```

we reach a range of valid time (`2012-06-17 18:12:01`) which can be evaluated again.